# printing console.log into debug message (HEX Code Written to Buffer)

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm tinkering w/ zwack (https://github.com/paixaop/zwack) and trying to see what(HEX) are being written to the buffer in an effort to try to simulate a FTMS machine/server

The code

```
onReadRequest(offset, callback) {
    debugFTMS('[SupportedPowerRangeCharacteristic] onReadRequest');
    let buffer = new Buffer.alloc(6);
    let at = 0;

    let minimumPower = 0;
    buffer.writeInt16LE(minimumPower, at);
    at += 2;

    let maximumPower = 1000;
    buffer.writeInt16LE(maximumPower, at);
    at += 2;

    let minimumIncrement = 1;
    buffer.writeUInt16LE(minimumIncrement, at);
    at += 2;

    debugFTMS('[SupportedPowerRangeCharacteristic] onReadRequest:' + buffer);
    console.log(buffer);

    callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, buffer);
  }
```

the `console.log(buffer)` command outputs

```
<Buffer 00 00 e8 03 01 00>
```

I would like to roll this up into the debug messages instead. Specifically into this line

```
debugFTMS('[SupportedPowerRangeCharacteristic] onReadRequest:' + buffer);
```

but the result I'm getting is some unprintable characters

```
ftms [SupportedPowerRangeCharacteristic] onReadRequest:� +0ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to format a buffer that way.

```
const util = require('util');
...
debugFTMS('[SupportedPowerRangeCharacteristic] onReadRequest:' + util.inspect(buffer));
```